# JPQL many to many select query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have two entity class and repository looks like following. I`m making jpql select query.

**Subscription.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Subscription")
public class Subscription implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="SubscriptionId", nullable=false)
    private Integer subscriptionId;

    @Column(name="BaseProductId", nullable=false)
    private Integer baseProductId;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="subscription")
    private List<Abc> abc;
}
```

**Abc.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="abc")
public class Abc implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="SubscriptionId", nullable=false)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="BaseProductId", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private List<Subscription> subscription;
}
```

**AbcRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface AbcRepository extends JpaRepository<Abc, Integer> {

    @Query(value="SELECT bpp FROM Abc bpp JOIN bpp.subscription s WHERE s.subscriptionId = ?1")
        public List<Abc> findBppm(Integer a);
    }
}
```

---

**Select query generating:**

**select ... from abc bp_ inner join abc_subscription ... inner join Subscription subscripti2_ on ... where subscripti2_.SubscriptionId=?**

... :- it have something at this place.

Though i`m joining abc and subscription, but in query hibernate creating one more entity separated by _. i.e. abc_subscription.

Any idea what i`m doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't get it, what's wrong with this query? Do you expect anything else? Are you just bothering about the names?

Comment: I`m expecting query:   select ... from abc bp_ inner join Subscription subscripti2_ on ... where subscripti2_.SubscriptionId=?

Comment: Why do you expect it to be like this? You are using a `ManyToMany` relationship so by default it will be represented with a join table `Abc_subscription` .

Comment: Thanks  @chsdk, I was not aware about this fact. Can i use manyToOne in my case?

Comment: It depends on the situation, it's up to your `design` and how is defined the relationship between `Abc` and `Subscription`.

Comment: In my case its manyTomany, but it don`t have any table like Abc_subscription.

Comment: There's no need to have a table `Abc_subscription` in your DB, it's just a virtual association between both tables, so just keep it as it is.

Comment: But at runtime exception is coming.    com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'mydb.Abc_subscription' doesn't exist

Comment: Then I think you should add `@JoinTable` annotation in your mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@ManyToMany` should be used in scenarios where there is a link table between entities.

If `@JoinTable` is not specified, the default link table used by the persistence provider would be the the concatenation of both entities separated by a "_". 
On top of that, f not specified the assumed column names in the link table would be the `@Id` field names as defined on the entity classes.

Try to follow the spec and adapt your situation accordingly: [ManyToMany javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ManyToMany.html)

Answer (score 1):

As a rule, avoid using Lists for Many to many relationships because this can cause problems when deleting a field from either of the entities.
Instead use Sets private Set<> abc = new HashSet<>();